# AngularDart multiselect operations get into endless loop in JS mode

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an AngularDart application that shows a multiple selection box like this:
[image: dart multiple selection]

I select one or more entry on the left, click > and it goes to the right. Works great in Dartium but in Javascript, the browser enters an endless loop that freezes the tab or even the browser (same in Chrome, Firefox and IE). I am using shadow_dom to make it work on other browsers and this was only working in Chrome with Dart 1.0.

The developer tools look like this:
[image: developer tools view of the multiple select]

I don't really see any specific code being executed on the Dart side, the event handlers visible above contain very little code meaningful to me. When I pause the Javascript endless loop, it brings me to this location:

```
AbstractNgRepeatDirective._onCollectionChange$1 (myappui.dart.js:14365)
(anonymous function) (VM5977:3)
relaxFnApply (myappui.dart.js:15739)
Scope_$watchCollection_closure4.call$3 (myappui.dart.js:7031)
_Watch.fn$3 (myappui.dart.js:7124)
Scope._digestHandleDirty$5 (myappui.dart.js:6535)
Scope._digestComputeLastDirty$0 (myappui.dart.js:6497)
Scope._digestWhileDirtyLoop$0 (myappui.dart.js:6433)
Scope.$$digest$0 (myappui.dart.js:6419)
Scope._autoDigestOnTurnDone$0 (myappui.dart.js:6269)
(anonymous function) (VM5930:3)
_rootRun (myappui.dart.js:20398)
_ZoneDelegate.run$2 (myappui.dart.js:26185)
NgZone._finishTurn$2 (myappui.dart.js:7267)
NgZone._onRunBase$4 (myappui.dart.js:7239)
NgZone._onRunUnary$5 (myappui.dart.js:7246)
(anonymous function) (VM5919:3)
_ZoneDelegate.runUnary$3 (myappui.dart.js:26192)
_CustomizedZone.runUnary$2 (myappui.dart.js:26419)
_BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded$2 (myappui.dart.js:26285)
_BaseZone_bindUnaryCallback_closure.call$1 (myappui.dart.js:26357)
invokeClosure_closure0.call$0 (myappui.dart.js:4573)
_IsolateContext.eval$1 (myappui.dart.js:2006)
_callInIsolate (myappui.dart.js:1740)
invokeClosure (myappui.dart.js:3224)
(anonymous function) (myappui.dart.js:3241)
invoke (shadow_dom.debug.js:2587)
dispatchBubbling (shadow_dom.debug.js:2535)
dispatchEvent (shadow_dom.debug.js:2489)
dispatchOriginalEvent (shadow_dom.debug.js:2467)
```

And the looping code:

```
_onCollectionChange$1: [function(collection) {
  var previousNode, cursor, arrayChange, t1, newRowOrder, $length, nextNode, index, value, row, childScope, t2, t3, block;
  previousNode = J.$index$asx(J.get$elements$x(this._blockHole), 0);
  cursor = this._blockHole;
  arrayChange = !J.$eq(this._lastCollection, collection);
  if (arrayChange)
    this._lastCollection = collection;
  t1 = J.getInterceptor(collection);
  if (typeof collection !== "object" || collection === null || collection.constructor !== Array && !t1.$isIterable)
    collection = [];
  newRowOrder = this._computeNewRows$2(collection, null);
  t1 = J.getInterceptor$asx(collection);
  $length = t1.get$length(collection);
  if (typeof $length !== "number")
    return H.iae($length);
  nextNode = null;
  index = 0;
  for (; index < $length; ++index) {
    value = t1.elementAt$1(collection, index);
    if (index >= newRowOrder.length)
      return H.ioore(newRowOrder, index);
    row = newRowOrder[index];
    if (row.get$startNode() != null) {
      childScope = row.get$scope();
      nextNode = previousNode;
      do
        nextNode = J.get$nextNode$x(nextNode);
      while (nextNode != null);
      if (J.$eq(row.get$startNode(), nextNode))
        ;
      else
        row.get$block().moveAfter$1(cursor);
      previousNode = row.get$endNode();
    } else
      childScope = this._directive$_scope.$$new$1$lazy(this.get$_shalow());
    t2 = J.getInterceptor$asx(childScope);
```

The while (nextNode!=null) never gets null...

```
do
  nextNode = J.get$nextNode$x(nextNode);
while (nextNode != null);
```

As I'm relatively new to Dart, I have to say that I don't have much clue as to where to look. Any suggestion ?

Relevant pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  angular: 0.9.4
  browser: any
  myapp:
    path: ../myappLib
  intl: any
  json_object: any
  petitparser: any
  shadow_dom: any
```

**UPDATE** The culprit is apparently shadow_dom. When I remove the  tag, it works in Chrome (obviously not in Firefox and IE anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared in more recent versions of shadow_dom (0.9.*)